# Calabash Android

Tags: android, calabash

I'm trying create calabash test for my android app.
I tried execute the command `calabash-android console` but it fail.
I tried resign the app but is failing.

Please see the attachment http://d.pr/i/C7wg

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if you are able to resign and run any other app?

Comment: did you try running `calabash-android resign <apk file>`

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solved this?

Comment: Hi, @stamhaney yes and I have the same output. ekims yes as you can see in the attachment. Dmitriy I am trying setup my environment again to see if it solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: @NLOL , can you show what your .calabash_Settings file looks like?

Comment: @stamhaney yes. {"keystore_location":"C:/Users/DEOL314106/.android/debug.keystore","keystore_password":"android","keystore_alias":"androiddebugkey"}
             Thanks

Comment: @stamhaney Hi, I found the solution for this problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: @DmitriyTarasov To solve this problem you need to make sure that calabash version is 0.4.8 (path Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems)

Comment: @NLOL Glad to hear this

Comment: @NLOL, your attachment link is not working. Kindly share your error logs.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error just because I signed wrong. Calabash android need to use ~/.android/debug.keystore for signing, password just use 'android'. More infos you can look at the wiki: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/Running-Calabash-Android

Answer (score 0):

You can use these steps which worked for me:

```
calabash-android build filename.apk
calabash-android resign filename.apk
calabash-android run filename.apk
calabash-android console filename.apk
```

Once you type console you have to write

```
start_test_server_in_background
```

Then you can apply query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps

```
bundle exec calabash-android setup
bundle exec calabash-android resign apk
bundle exec calabash-android gen
bundle exec calabash-android run apk
```

Answer (score 0):

After resigning your app, run `calabash-android console <path to apk file>` again. Then run `reinstall_apps`. After this, you should be able to run `start_test_server_in_background` to launch the app and execute your console commands.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any APK for your app. For example, I use this command:

```
ADB_DEVICE_ARG=emulator-5554 calabash-android run ../build/apk/myapp-debug-unaligned.apk
```

This is the debug version of the app. Can you see if you have another APK generated from your project and try to use this one?